# EntityValue evaluation behaviour

Tags: evaluation, entity

I'm puzzled by a behaviour of `EntityValue`, where I find it being unevaluated. Here is a minimal example. Consider the following custom `EntityStore`:

```
store = EntityStore[{
   "Group" -> <|
     "Entities" -> <|
       "GroupA" -> <|
         "name" -> "Group A",
         "size" -> 2,
         "members" -> {
           Entity["Individual", "Claus"],
           Entity["Individual", "Andrea"]
           }
         |>,
       "GroupB" -> <|
         "name" -> "Group B",
         "size" -> 2,
         "members" -> {
           Entity["Individual", "John"],
           Entity["Individual", "Claudia"]
           }
         |>
       |>
     |>,
   "Individual" -> <|
     "Entities" -> <|
       "Claus" -> <|"name" -> "Claus Smith", "age" -> 25|>,
       "Andrea" -> <|"name" -> "Andrea Fisher", "age" -> 35|>,
       "John" -> <|"name" -> "John Allen", "age" -> 45|>,
       "Claudia" -> <|"name" -> "Claudia Wilson", "age" -> 60|>
       |>
     |>
   }
  ]
```

Let's register it:

```
EntityRegister[store]
```

and then query it:

```
assoc = EntityValue["Group", "PropertyAssociation"]
```

which gives as expected:

```
{<|
  EntityProperty["Group", "members"] -> {Entity["Individual", "Claus"], Entity["Individual", "Andrea"]}, 
  EntityProperty["Group", "name"] -> "Group A", 
  EntityProperty["Group", "size"] -> 2
|>, 
<|
  EntityProperty["Group", "members"] -> {Entity["Individual", "John"], Entity["Individual", "Claudia"]}, 
  EntityProperty["Group", "name"] -> "Group B", 
  EntityProperty["Group", "size"] -> 2
|>}
```

Now let's say we'd like to make this association hierarchical by replacing the Individual properties by their own property associations:

```
ds = assoc /. {Entity["Individual", n_] :> EntityValue[Entity["Individual", n], "PropertyAssociation"]}
```

This - unexpectedly to me - leaves the inner EntityValue expressions unevaluated:

```
{<|
  EntityProperty["Group", "members"] -> {EntityValue[Entity["Individual", "Claus"], "PropertyAssociation"], EntityValue[Entity["Individual", "Andrea"], "PropertyAssociation"]}, 
  EntityProperty["Group", "name"] -> "Group A", 
  EntityProperty["Group", "size"] -> 2|>,
 <|EntityProperty["Group", "members"] -> {EntityValue[Entity["Individual", "John"],  "PropertyAssociation"], EntityValue[Entity["Individual", "Claudia"], "PropertyAssociation"]}, 
  EntityProperty["Group", "name"] -> "Group B", 
  EntityProperty["Group", "size"] -> 2
|>
}
```

What's going on? Strangely, the inner `EntityValue` expressions evaluate when we somehow query them directly:

```
Lookup[ds, EntityProperty["Group", "members"]]
```

correctly yields

```
{{<|EntityProperty["Individual", "age"] -> 25, 
   EntityProperty["Individual", "name"] -> "Claus Smith"|>,
  <|EntityProperty["Individual", "age"] -> 35, 
   EntityProperty["Individual", "name"] -> "Andrea Fisher"|>},
 {<|EntityProperty["Individual", "age"] -> 45, 
   EntityProperty["Individual", "name"] -> "John Allen"|>,
  <|EntityProperty["Individual", "age"] -> 60, 
   EntityProperty["Individual", "name"] -> "Claudia Wilson"
|>}}
```

Why is this bugging me? I'd like to use this kind of replace mechanism to build up a hierarchical association expression from a hierarchical entity Store. Imagine a cascade of one-to-many relationships, like Continent -> Country -> Region -> City -> Neighbourhood" or something similar. I'd like to build up a hierarchy of associations by iteratively replacing the list of child-entities by their property associations.

So how can I control the evaluation of `EntityValue`?

Thanks.

Comment: Forgot to mention that I'm using Mathematica 12.0.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ds = Replace[
  assoc, {Entity["Individual", n_] :> 
    EntityValue[Entity["Individual", n], "PropertyAssociation"]}, 
  Infinity]
```

or create a list of rules (using `Normal`) from the Association to use `ReplaceAll`.

```
ds = Normal[assoc] /. 
 Entity["Individual", n_] :> 
  EntityValue[Entity["Individual", n], "PropertyAssociation"]
```

Comment: Wow, `Replace` indeed works here. But I'm very puzzled by this! The replace action actually wasn't the issue here, as the replace itself worked. It was only the evaluation of the replacement-code that didn't take place. Why would `Replace` vs. `ReplaceAll` make a difference with respect to Evaluation of code after replacement?

Comment: Because we are dealing with Associations. ```ReplaceAll``` will work as expected with a list of rules. Use ```Normal[assoc]```.